# Upgrading Meteor v1.0 to v1.2: server not recognized under Meteor methods under /lib

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, client-server

The following code architecture works in up to `Meteor 1.0` but breaks in `Meteor 1.2` 
Any insights/suggestions are appreciated. 
Note: I'm using `meteor update --release 1.2` as my method to ugprade.

in `server/file1.coffee`:

```
class ClassA
    {code for the class} 
@MyObj = new ClassA()
```

in `/lib/collections/file2.coffee`:

```
Meteor.methods 
   myFunction : ->
      if Meteor.isServer
          console.log 'isServer'
      if MyObj?
        {do stuff}
```

Note that while `myFunction` is defined in `/lib` directory and called from `/client` it runs on the server in Meteor version `1.0`, as evidenced by logs printed from within that function under `Meteor.isServer`. This is not the case in version `1.2`.  Under `1.2`, `Meteor.isServer` is never true and it's log doesn't print.

Has anyone seen anything like this issue ?

EDIT: the closest issue I've been able to find on this anywhere is: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5113 but this post is not very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, client-side code in `client/` was at no time allowed to "see" code in the `server/` directory, because that directory is only loaded on the server side of the Meteor application. That also means that code in `lib/` **cannot** see code in the `server/`directory, **if the `lib/` code is called on the client side**. If you have client code in `lib/` that depends on code from the `server/` directory, then either move that code from `server/` to `lib/` or check whether the code is executed on the server or the client. You can use [Meteor.isServer](http://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-isServer) and [Meteor.isClient](http://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-isClient) for that purpose.

You might also want to take a look at [Meteor load order](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order) and [special directories](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories) of Meteor to check whether that it still is doing what it was doing in version 1.0 of Meteor.

Comment: Striezel, please see my edited question.  I wasn't clear before on the precise issue I was seeing but hopefully now it is.  Also, thank you for your help thus far.